# Zend Framework application with login and signup pages on one domain and other pages on the subdomain

Tags: php, zend-framework, subdomain

We develop a zend framework application and want that signup pages and login pages were on our domain for example http://domain.com (now all pages are on http://domain.com) and other pages (where you have to be redirected after authentification) on subdomain: http://subdomain.domain.com.
Could you please tell how to solve it?
Thank you for any ideas.

Comment: We have an application now on http://domain.com and login page is something like this http://domain.com/login and http://domain.com/signup after loggin user is redirected to http://domain.com/controller, but we need to redirect to http://subdomain.domain.com/controller. After loggin out user must be http://domain.com/login. I don't quite understand how to make it.

Comment: Later on maybe we'll need to more domains for users, so some users are redirected to subdomain1, other on subdomain2. Thank you any ideas how to make it.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this kind of thing in a major ZF app of mine.  It's a complicated 3-part question, but hopefully this will get you started in the right direction.

**First** is the session cookie.  You'll need to use a wildcard domain parameter when you set the session cookie.  In your Bootstrap or somewhere prior to when you would normally start your session, include a line such as:

```
Zend_Session::start(array('cookie_domain' => '.domain.com'));
```

Note the dot (".") prior to "domain.com".  This makes the cookie applicable for `domain.com` as well as all subdomains under it.

**Second** is the URL's throughout your site.  You can use the Redirector action helper's `gotoUrl()` method.  At the end of an action method when you want to redirect the user, use a line like this:

```
$this->_redirector->gotoUrl('http://domain.com/somewhere/else');
```

Of course, you may want to assemble the URL string by other means such as storing the domain in a configuration parameter and concatenating the path using one of ZF's native methods of generating a URL path.  See the documentation for `Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Redirector` for more.  You'll also need to be careful about all URL's on your site and make sure the right domain is included in each link.

**Third** is how your app interprets routes when subdomains are involved.  There are a few ways to accomplish this, but one is to create a module within your app that corresponds to each subdomain you want to use.  Then use a [Controller Plugin](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html) to intercept ZF's normal routing mechanism and set the module name appropriately based on the subdomain.  Something like:

```
class My_Controller_Plugin_RouteMySubdomains extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract {

    public function routeShutdown(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) {
        $hostname = $request->getHttpHost();
        if (strlen($hostname) > strlen('domain.com')) {
            $moduleName = preg_replace("/\.domain\.com$/", '', $hostname);
            $request->setModuleName($moduleName);
        }
    }
}
```

You'll need to tell ZF to use this plugin.  If you're using `Zend_Application` with an `application.ini` file for basic configuration, you'll need to add a line like this:

```
resources.frontController.plugins.routeMySubdomains = "My_Controller_Plugin_RouteMySubdomains"
```

Good luck!